# Ordenar datos de n listas cronológicamente

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, ordenamiento

Tengo varias listas de datos de la siguiente manera:

```
fechas = [datetime1, datetime2, datetime3, ....]
operaciones = ['GA', 'GA', 'PA', ...]
```

La lista operaciones es una colección de strings que está ordenada cronológicamente y existe correspondencia con los elementos de la lista fechas que es una colección de objetos datetime, esto quiere decir que el elemento `operaciones[0]` corresponde con la fecha `fechas[0]`, bien así tengo varios archivos con ambas listas que corresponden a mediciones diferentes.

Mi problema es el siguiente: Quisiera crear una sola lista con los elementos de todas las listas ordenado cronológicamente, pero sinceramente no se muy bien como hacerlo, tengo dos ideas pero no se como implementarlas del todo, por ejemplo supongamos que tengo 12 listas (6 de operaciones 6 de fechas) se me ocurre comparar el primer elemento de cada lista fechas y cuándo encuentre el menor insertar en la nueva lista el elemento correspondiente a esa fecha de la lista operaciones, PERO hacer 6 comparaciones me supondra mucho código y muy poca eficiencia, tengo otra idea que sería usar diccionarios en vez de listas un solo diccionario de esta forma: `diccionario = {datetime1: 'GA', datetime2: 'GA', datetime3: 'PA'}`  esto me supondría tener 6 diccionarios (ordenados cronológicamente de manera ascendente) en vez de 12 listas, para obtener un diccionario o lista con todas las operaciones simplemente tendría que agregar todos los elementos no importando el orden y después ordenándolos atendiendo a la llave que es un objeto datetime (operaciones con fechas) pero aquí me surgen algunas dudas: ¿cómo se ordena un diccionario? en dado caso que alguna fecha de algún archivo se repita ¿cómo la ordenaría?

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si hay posibilidad de que una fecha se repita usar diccionarios se complica ya que la clave de un diccionario es siempre única. Se puede hacer que el valor del diccionario sea una lista y añadir a cada key(fecha) todos los string que coincidan con esa fecha.

Creo que es complicarse un poco, podrías simplemente concatenar las listas y luego ordenar. Para que sea más eficiente, en vez de crear dos listas enormes resultado de concatenar todas las fechas y todas las operaciones puedes usar [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) que crea un iterador.

Para proporcionar un ejemplo voy a crear tres parejas de listas fecha-operaciones. Para crear la listas de objetos `datetime` he usado como base la fecha actual y luego le resto dias para crear distintas fechas solo a modo de ejemplo.

```
import datetime
import itertools

base = datetime.datetime.today()


fechas1 = [base-datetime.timedelta(days=1), base-datetime.timedelta(days=3), base-datetime.timedelta(days=5)]
operaciones1 = ['S1', 'S2', 'S3']

fechas2 = [base-datetime.timedelta(days=2), base-datetime.timedelta(days=6), base-datetime.timedelta(days=8)]
operaciones2 = ['S4', 'S5', 'S6']

fechas3 = [base-datetime.timedelta(days=5), base-datetime.timedelta(days=7), base-datetime.timedelta(days=8)]
operaciones3 = ['S7', 'S8', 'S9']


fechas = itertools.chain(fechas1, fechas2, fechas3)
operaciones = itertools.chain(operaciones1, operaciones2, operaciones3)
ordenadas = [op for fecha, op in sorted(zip(fechas, operaciones))]

print(ordenadas)
```

Retorna:

> ['S6', 'S9', 'S8', 'S5', 'S3', 'S7', 'S2', 'S4', 'S1']

Esto nos da como puede verse la lista de todas las operaciones ordenadas de acuerdo a sus listas `fechas` correspondientes. El orden es de más antigua (indice 0) a más reciente.

Comment: Muchas gracias excelente solución, ¿crees que funcione igual si en vez de usar datetime uso timestamp en fechas?

Comment: No deberias tener problemas, el código simplemente ordena de acuerdo a las listas `fechas`, estas pueden contener cualquier tipo de dato ordenable como enteros, floats, caracteres, strings, segundos desde época, etc. Si tienes algún problema edita la pregunta aportando algo de más información de como obtines los datos de las listas `fechas` y si usas otras librerías como Numpy o Pandas para procesar los datos.

Comment: De nuevo muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

La solución que te ha dado @FJSevilla sería una solución general. Aunque utilice *iteradores* con el fin de ahorrar recursos, aún necesita cargar todos los datos en memoria con el fin de hacer la ordenación.

Asumiendo que los datos ya están ordenados cronológicamente en sus respectivas listas, existe una solución mucho más eficiente, y coste mínimo, para mezclarlas: las **pilas de prioridad** ([heapq](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/heapq.html)).

Supongamos que tenemos una listas de *operaciones* y sus correspondientes listas de *fechas*. Podemos crear la pila de prioridad de la siguiente forma:

```
import heapq

iter_operaciones = [
    zip(fechas1, operaciones1),
    zip(fechas2, operaciones2),
    zip(fechas3, operaciones3),
]
h = heapq.merge(*iter_operaciones)
```

Para procesar esta pila, o bien se pasa a una lista (`list(h)`) o bien se usa `for` como con cualquier iterador:

```
for (fecha, op) in h:
    print("{:%Y-%m-%d}: {}".format(fecha, op))
```

Hay tener en cuenta que no se crea ninguna lista intermedia, ya que se lee el dato de cada iterador a medida que haga falta. Incluso sería posible leer directamente los datos desde cada fichero en disco, sin volcar el fichero completo a memoria, por lo que se podría procesar cantidades ingentes de datos sin malgastar recursos.

Por ejemplo, supongamos que las operaciones están en ficheros de texto en lugar de un lista, una operación por línea de texto. El código sería muy parecido:

```
import heapq

with open("operaciones1.txt") as f1,
     open("operaciones2.txt") as f2,
     open("operaciones3.txt") as f3:

  iter_operaciones = [
    zip(fechas1, f1),
    zip(fechas2, f2),
    zip(fechas3, f3),
  ]
  h = heapq.merge(*iter_operaciones)

  for (fecha, op) in h:
      print("{:%Y-%m-%d}: {}".format(fecha, op))
```

Comment: ¿Podría tener fechas1 en un archivo de texto también? o solo como lista ya cargada.

Comment: Sí que se podría. Mientras sea *Iterable*, puede ser lo que quieras: lista, fichero, generador, etc.